# Excel Conditional Formatting and Data Transfer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm reaching my limits with Excel, so I'd welcome any advice:

**1. Conditional Formatting in Timeline "Schedule":**
I want to use conditional formatting in the timeline schedule (on the right side) to highlight cells with job abbreviations when multiple jobs are assigned to a work group on the same day. This means there will be two or more text-green cells in the same column, corresponding to a selected work group in the first column of the table. I suspect using some form of INDEX/MATCH that ignores empty cells would help.

Schedule table with formula for schedule cells:
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV1wu.png)**

Conditional formatting:
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOr8o.png)**

**2. Transfer Work Abbreviation from "Schedule" to "Work Group Plan" and "Customer Plan" Timelines on different sheet:**
I need to somehow transfer the job character abbreviation from the "Schedule" sheet to the timelines on the "Work Group Plan" and "Customer Plan" sheets. The issue is that current plans only work on a formula that counts the number of non-empty cells in the column for a given date and marks it if it's greater than 0 for a particular work group. VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH doesn't work because the work group is listed multiple times in the source column, and I need only the row where there is some text in the schedule.

Work group & client plan:
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH8Jh.png)**

Conditional formatting (to paint cells green) is then applied only to non-blank cells.

**Any assistance or guidance on implementing these functionalities would be greatly appreciated!**

What I tried:

1. I tried tinkering with nested conditional formatting formulas applied on the cells in the schedule combining IF/COUNTIFS/AND.
2. No progress here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. There's a lot really going on in your post. In fact, it is really not a question but a requirement. Please check on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which guides you on how to properly post a question here. Please break down your questions too. A simple direct question will be most likely answered faster. Do you need to tackle the conditional formatting first or the formula?

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you really could do with a complete solution to your challenge. There are several ways to achieve the end goal and I have examples of more complex work schedules.

I would break the problem down into 3 parts.

Part 1 : the data table where all the work is captured. Using the standard filters it is easy to filter by work group or customer and then you don't need to duplicate the information on separate sheets.

Part 2 : the schedule / timeline. I would advise to create a dynamic timeline that works from =Today(). The advantage of this is it will always refresh itself and require no manual intervention. You can always have Today() - a certain number of days if you want to show the previous period. I also conditionally highlight the "today" column so people using the file can see exactly where you are on that day.

Part 3 : The graphic under the schedule as you show in your example can be made up of cells with text that triggers conditional formatting. Excel can do some pretty clever things with conditional formatting. I find the simplest is to add an additional column somewhere in the sheet that can carry a code to drive the colours.

However, I found that still limiting for the application I was working on and moved to a VBA that inserts shapes of the correct length (date driven: x-axis) and Project driven position (y-axis). The big advantage of doing this is you can add commentary, labels, colours, different shapes (e.g. milestones) and a single button use to refresh the diagram.

That's much more of a project where you will need some VBA skills.
An example from one of mine;
[Timeline Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRCaB.png)